# Wordpress - Appending scripts to footer cancels "wp_enqueue_scripts"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In functions.php I have added the follow :

> add_action('wp_footer', '_head_js');

which accesses the following function :

```
function _head_js()
{ ?>
    <script>
        window.onload = (() =>
        {
            categ = document.getElementById('cat');
            categ.firstElementChild.innerHTML = 'Categories';  
        });
    </script>
<?php }
```

Now my `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '_load');` fails to work anymore.

Our _load function :

```
function _load()
{
wp_enqueue_style('main', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style('icons', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css');
wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', false);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody encounters a similar error, the following was the issue:

I was loading a script on `window.onload` in the footer section, which blocked any other scripts from loading any further.

Loading the script without `window.onload` works flawlessly( although offers some loading visuals which I would have preferred not to happen).

Answer (score 0):

please check view source and check is main.js loaded on the page?

if not Please try this-

```
    function _load() {
                wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
                wp_enqueue_style('icons', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css');
                wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', false);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue was that I was loading scripts in the footer although one of my scripts used window.onload :)